# Selenium Webdriver VBA code for double click and enter number into the textbox

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have written a VBA code to do double click on the webpage by using the following code. After double click, cursor placed at the element. Now, how will I get the cursor focused element and enter value in that element?

```
Public driver As New Selenium.WebDriver
Sub samp()

driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.get "https://sample.com/QuickEntry.aspx"

**driver.FindElementByClass("s0s2s0").ClickDouble**
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
driver.FindElementByClass("s0s2s0").innerText = "Your value goes here"
```

The above code work on input box and text area present in HTML DOM.

Comment: No, I cant save the data if I do like that. Only if I double click and enter the data, it will get saved.

Comment: Yes, but the values not updated at the double clicked input box.